# Значок "Поддерживает команды" в дискорд боте, используя discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, discord

Сегодня увидел у ботов значки "Поддерживает команды", и захотел себе такой же. Я добавляю команды, но по-прежнему значок не выдается. Использую discord.py[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

class PersistentViewBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
    async def setup_hook(self):
        await bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))

guild_id = 123456

bot = PersistentViewBot()

# Обработчик события подключения к Discord
@bot.hybrid_command(name='embed', description="Выводит embed сообщение", with_app_command=True)
@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def embed(ctx, description:str):
    embed = discord.Embed(description=description,color=0x2f3136)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
bot.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Это вроде как могут получить лишь верифицированные боты (те, которые есть на 100+ серверах).

Comment: если с модуля disnake писать, то он автоматически появляется, а с discord.py нет.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
@bot.command()
async def command(ctx):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  await ctx.send('Я робот')
```

Несколько раз введите /command значок появится

Comment: то и дело что не работает

Answer (score 0):

Создай бота с таким кодом:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()  # Используй нужные интенты
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents)

@bot.slash_command(description='Получаем значок для бота')
async def command(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Я робот')

bot.run('YOUR_TOKEN')
```

После чего перейди на [портал разработчиков, мои апликации](https://discord.com/developers/applications) и выбери нужного бота. Нажми на OAuth2 - general. В самом низу будет строка "`Default Authorization Link`", в ней выбери "`In-app Authorization`". В scopes выбери `bot` и `applications.commands`. В `bot permissions` отметь `Administrator` (*см. скрин*)

[image: или сделай всё как на картинке]

После этого пригласи бота на новый сервер через кнопку в его профиле и на новом сервере пару раз пропиши `/command`

[image: как на картинке]

Значок должен выдастся автоматически.

Comment: Это скорее диснейк, и bot.slash_command просто напросто не существует.

Comment: Я понимаю что это диснейк, но значок получить только так) можно использовать этот код на своём боте а позже написать весь функционал на удобной тебе библиотеке. Код проверил - работает. Значок выдался автоматически на новом боте.

Comment: забыл добавить, вверху кода так же допишите `import disnake` и `from disnake.ext import commands`

Comment: смысл в том, чтобы появилось на discord.py а не на disnake